# can you put ubuntu on a disk as a boot disk to make another computer use it for operation

Tags: system-installation

I currently have a computer on which I want to replace operating system. Is it possible to burn Ubuntu to a disk as a boot installer so I can install it on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The boot disk can install over the current OS on your computer if you need it to.

Comment: do you just pull it offline and burn it to a disk?